# verification of SQL Managed Instance migration

Tags: azure, azure-sql-managed-instance, sqlmigrations

is there a way to verify that a SQL Server to an Azure SQL Managed Instance migration was successful? More detailed question would be, how can I check that there is no data corruption? Is there is not, it is because CHECKSUM in Backups is enough?

Thanks! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you are doing the migration. If you are taking backups -> upload to Blob -> Restore to Azure SQL MI, then taking backups with checksum and verify option should be good enough.

If you want, you can run DBCC for peace of mind but I haven't seen any issues during migrations.

Hopefully this helps

Comment: Thanks for the tip Rizwan. Will try the DBCC. Microsoft told me that if it is completed should be fine. That´s what I think but the customer want to check it for compliance reasons.

Comment: Also one other thing to mention. If you have any corruption, it is usually caught behind the scenes because there are about 2-3 additional copies of the database to prevent data loss in the case if one of the drive. If there is corruption, you should open a case with MS support and they are pretty good about it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/transact-sql-tsql-differences-sql-server#dbcc